# Flutter build release AndroidX incompatibilities

Tags: flutter

When I run the project on emulator or a real device it runs perfect.
but when I try to build a release with

```
flutter build apk --release
```

or

```
flutter build appbundle
```

it gives me this error

```
*******************************************************************************************
The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.
See URL for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
*******************************************************************************************
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

[although I tried this](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility)

Comment: did you clean your android project?  after clean and rebuild in android project my flutter command worked

Comment: the problem is firebase messaging I removed it and is works and I tried all the approaches to add it but it failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar error and put the following lines in gradle.properties file in /android folder of my project.

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

But according to comments section, main problem is not the AndroidX warning but a problem in assembleBuild task of Gradle regarding a library.

Looks like the question is not about AndroidX.

Comment: when i put these lines the app don't run on emulator and same error
but when I remove these lines the app runs on emulator and same error when building release

Comment: weird. I have no problems running the emulator with those lines in the properties file. Then i am out of ideas, sorry. But you did the AndroidX Migration from the Android Studion IDE ?

Comment: it tells me no usages found in the project

Comment: perhaps what you see regarding AndroidX is not the problem. Go to Android folder and do this in terminal: ./gradlew assembleRelease -d     This might reveal the real problem.

Comment: I figured out that the problem is firebase_messaging: ^1.0.5
I tried many versions and stil